# Add side button in Brackets extension

Tags: adobe-brackets

I'm developing Brackets extension and want to add side button. What module can do that?

[image: Brackets sidebar]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: [There is no module or API for it](https://trello.com/c/psg0qmGR/552-toolbar-api-guidelines-for-extension-icons), you have to do it yourself.

Helpful answer:
You can use this snipped to add a Button to the toolbar:

```
$toolbarButton = $(document.createElement("a"))
    .attr("id", "phanect-extensionname-toolbar-icon")
    .attr("href", "#")
    .attr("title", Strings.TOOLBAR_ICON_TOOLTIP)
    .on("click", function () {
        // Handle click
    })
    .appendTo($("#main-toolbar .buttons"));
```

For the icon of the Button and the css see [Extension Icon Guidelines](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/wiki/Extension-Icon-Guidelines)